# Crypted Chat - Problems whit BufferedReader

Tags: java, wrapper, bufferedreader

I'm trying to implement a simple crypted chat; btw, I have problems while using wrappers.
The Cypher class works well and it (de)crypt single bytes.
Also, I have the `CypherOutputStream` and `CypherInputStream` classes, which respectively extend `FilterOutputStream` and `FilterInputStream`. They works great alone, but when I try to wrap the `CypherInputStream` around a `BufferedReader` (or a `Scanner`), it just stops trying to read data.
Specifically, debugging the code, it seems that the `BufferedReader` object correctly invoke the `CypherInputStream` object read. Then, it reads the whole word (byte by byte), but it can't be able to correctly read the end of line (and then stopping from read); so, it continues to invoke the `CypherInputStream read()`, expecting a new byte. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

Here is the `CypherInputStream`:

```
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CypherInputStream extends FilterInputStream
{
    private Cypher  cypher;

    public CypherInputStream(InputStream in, Cypher c)
    {
        super(in);
        cypher = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        return cypher.decrypt((byte) in.read(););
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] data, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
        int i = -1;
        for (i = off; i < off + len; i++)
            data[i] = (byte) this.read();
        return i - off;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] data) throws IOException
    {
        return this.read(data, 0, data.length);
    }
}
```

Below, you can see the main code lines of the `CryptedChatHandler` object, that handle the chat communication.

```
BufferedWriter userToSocket = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new CypherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), cypher)));
BufferedReader socketToUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new CypherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), cypher)));
...
while (status == YOU)
    if (inFromUser.hasNextLine())
         String s = inFromUser.nextLine();
    userToSocket.write(s.concat("\r\n"));

...
while (status == OTHER)
     String s = socketToUser.readLine();
     System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: update: it seems that using a `PrintStream` rather than a `BufferedWriter` or a `PrintWriter` it works great.
I don't know why to be honest.